# Design considerations for loading an SQLite Database for the first time

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am creating a system that will store objects in an SQLite Database. I am using C# with System.Data.SQLite.

This is a "best practise" kind of question - is it better, when loading a Database, to:

a) Create the SQLite database programatically if it doesn't exist

or

b) Connect to a pre-created database using an SQLite database creation tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go for a mix:

> a) Create the SQLite database programatically if it doesn't exist

and optionally:

> b) Connect to a pre-created database using an SQLite database creation
>   tool

Because If You implement A, switching to scenario B would be as simple as copying a file during installation.

Comment: Ok, now it's time for some context!

What about when using WCF services, and the constructor is called everytime a client connects to the server where the database is hosted?

Comment: Well, Checking if the database exists doesn't cost much. First client would have to wait before the database is created. If you want to avoid that, then you can supply a pre-created file during install.